# Is it possible to analyze gpu memory in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gpu

I wonder if there is any way to view raw vram memory of the gpu in visual studio. Just like when opening the memory layout from withn visual studio which shows the process memory.

Most topics are about gpu usage, i actually want to the raw bits and bytes of the gpu mem during my app execution. I know NVIDIA have a utility called Nsight, but I want general utility.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could use [GPU Usage tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/gpu-usage?view=vs-2019). I think this tool could meet your needs.

To start the GPU Usage tool:

In the main menu, choose Debug > Performance and Diagnostics (or, on the keyboard, press Alt+F2).

In the Performance and Diagnostics hub, check the box next to GPU Usage. Optionally, check the boxes next to other tools you're interested in. You can run several performance and diagnostics tools concurrently to get a fuller picture of your app's performance.

Starting with Visual Studio 2017, you can open the report with [GPUView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/using-gpuview) and [Windows Performance Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-analyzer).